# Polynomial modulo n

Tags: polynomials, primality-test

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AKS_primality_test

[image]

How can I interpret what the "mod n" means?

I have watched the [Numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HvMSRWTE2mI) on the AKS primality test, and based on that, I am assuming that "mod n" means the remainder when dividing by each of the coefficients.

$$ (x - 1)^5 \equiv (x^5 - 1) \pmod 5 $$
$$ x^5 - 5x^4 + 10x^3 - 10x^2 + 5x - 1 \equiv x^5 - 1 \pmod 5 $$
$$ 1x^5 - 0x^4 + 0x^3 - 0x^2 + 0x - 1 \equiv 1x^5 - 1 $$
$$ x^5 - 1 \equiv x^5 - 1 $$

Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually covered in more detail in an introductory number theory or abstract algebra textbook, and is referred to as "modular arithmetic."

Writing that two quantities are congruent/equivalent$\pmod n$ (this is said "modulo $n$") means that the two quantities produce the same remainder when divided by $n$.  Thus, we can write $15\equiv -1\equiv 7\pmod 8$.

We often want to work with polynomials, though; in this case, we can simplify expressions (as you have in the question) by reducing each of the coefficients of the polynomial to their "residues" (remainders) modulo $n$.

The big "watchout" in modular arithmetic is that, although we can multiply, add, and subtract freely, division isn't always guaranteed.  Instead, we work with "inverses" of a number.  Long story short, an integer $a$ is the inverse of $x$ modulo $n$ if (and only if) $ax\equiv 1\pmod{n}$.  We write $a\equiv x^{-1}\pmod n$.  It can be shown that the inverse always exists if $x$ and $n$ are coprime.

All that to say: yes, your approach in the question is correct.

Comment: My wording is a bit off regarding variables vs. indeterminants (see Hagen von Eitzen's answer), but the rest of it should be true. :)

Comment: Can you give an example of when division doesn't work out? I don't quite understand.

Comment: @kukac67 Find $x$ such that $2x\equiv 1\pmod 4$.  You can't--"normal" division by two would make $x=\frac{1}{2}$, but we are restricted to integers in modular arithmetic.  You have to multiply $2$ by some number $a$ such that $2a \equiv 1\pmod 4$, but multiples of $2$ can't be equivalent to $1$ (so no such $a$ exists).

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is correct if $x$ (and $a$?) is an *indeterminate*.

To add a bit of complication, if $x$ is a *variable* that can take integer values, additional congruences are possible, e.g., $x^2+x\equiv 0\pmod 2$. But nevertheless, any result obtained by reducing coefficients modulo the module remains corrct also for the second interpertation.